# Decomposing python list i.e creating variables from python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What is the best way in python to convert a list of small length (3 or 4) into variables. Actually I want to do the opposite of creating a list like this in Python 3.

```
some_python_list=[a,b,c,d]
```

So what I want is something which does

```
a,b,c,d=some_python_list.decompose(4) #while I know alist is of length 4
```

So I can save myself from

```
a=some_python_list[0]
b=some_python_list[1]
c=some_python_list[2]
d=some_python_list[3]
```

or

```
a,b,c,d=some_python_list[0],some_python_list[1],some_python_list[2],some_python_list[3]
```

Comment: If you know the list has 4 elements, it's just `a, b, c, d = some_python_list`.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the length of the list, then you can use a number of variables equal to the number of elements in the list:

```
some_python_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
a, b, c, d = some_python_list
print(a, b, c, d)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```